# multiple move operations and data processes in work thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

main thread--> start workthread-->StartStage(get list of positions for data process) --> move to one position --> data sampling **--> data collection-->data analysis------>data sampling**

basically, work thread does the data sampling **--> data collection-->data analysis------>data sampling** loop for one positioin until press stop or target is obtained.

my questions:

After work thread finishs the loop for one positioin, it would end itself.

now how to make the work thread moves to the next position to do the data process loop after work thread finish one position work, would not end itself until data process for all the positions are done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just put a loop around the data processing part to advance to the next "position"?  All in the worker thread.  Also, will there be multiple worker threads working on different "positions"? Much more work required if multiple threads are involved. Need more info.

Comment: for that he needs to understand at least basics of synchronisation. this is "dead parrot question"

Answer (score 0):

- Make a ConcurrentQueue<> with all the positions
- At the end of a position let a workerthread Dequeue a new position from the ConcurrentQueue<> and process it. This can be a simple while loop.
- If the Dequeue fails there are no more positions and the thread exits